# Summarise first row meeting a condition

Tags: r, dplyr, conditional-statements, lag, summarize

Let's say I have this data frame:

```
    df <- data.frame(
    party = c("A", "A", "B", "A", "B"), 
    votes = c(100, 99, 98, 97, 96), 
    elected = c(1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0)
)

  party votes elected
1     A   100       1
2     A    99       1
3     B    98       1
4     A    97       0
5     B    96       0
```

I want to compute a new variable which is the votes of the challenger candidate, this is the votes of the first non-elected candidate form a different party. The result would be:

```
  party votes elected votes_challenge
1     A   100       1              96
2     A    99       1              96
3     B    98       1              97
4     A    97       0              NA
5     B    96       0              NA
```

I have tried with `first()` and `lag()` using a condition with `which()` with no luck for now. Would appreciate any help.

Comment: What is the logic how do you identify the row with the "challenger candidate"?

Comment: Theres is probably a way of replicating the result you would like from this data. 

But I think what might make that method more replicable would be if you could supply a contest id. 

For example if the data looked more the like this:


```
df <- data.frame(
        election_id = c('001', '002', '003', '003', '002'),
        party = c("A", "A", "B", "A", "B"), 
        votes = c(100, 99, 98, 97, 96), 
        elected = c(1, 1, 1, 0, 0)
)
```

You probably have an easier time re-using through the solution

Comment: All observations belong to the same election. The challenger candidate is the first unelected one that belongs to other party. For example, first row is from party A, so the challenger is the most voted unelected candidate from a different party (i.e. B), which is in row 5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try with a function

```
library(dplyr)

get_opposite_votes <- function(df, group) { 
   df %>% filter(party != group & elected == 0) %>% slice(1L) %>% pull(votes)
}


df %>%
  group_by(party) %>%
  mutate(new = get_opposite_votes(., first(party))) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  #If needed to have NA values where elected = 0
  mutate(new = replace(new, elected == 0, NA))

#  party votes elected   new
#  <fct> <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl>
#1 A       100       1    96
#2 A        99       1    96
#3 B        98       1    97
#4 A        97       0    NA
#5 B        96       0    NA
```

Answer (score 1):

This is one option using `fuzzyjoin`-package

```
library(fuzzyjoin)
library(tidyverse)

fuzzy_left_join(df, df %>% 
                  arrange(party, elected, desc(votes)) %>% 
                  group_by(party) %>% slice(1) , 
                by = c("party", "elected"), match_fun = list(`!=`, `>`)) %>%
select(ends_with("x"), votes.y)  

  party.x votes.x elected.x votes.y
1       A     100         1      96
2       A      99         1      96
3       B      98         1      97
4       A      97         0      NA
5       B      96         0      NA
```

Maybe this works for you